# SQL - Setting a variable to value of column in another table

Tags: sql, variables

I'm developing a sports app which allows users the view fixtures between 2 teams.
The **fixtures class** takes the following attributes:

```
public Fixture(int id, int tournamentId, 
                String gender, String section, 
                String team1, String team2, 
                String date, String time, String venue, String court)
```

The data gets pulled from an online database, but I'm having some trouble with the SQL query. The two tables I'm using is

1. **TournamentLogs** (info about teams in tournament)
   Has the following columns:

   Id (PK), TournamentId (FK), Team, Gender, Section
2. **TournamentFixtures** (info on different fixtures)
   Has the following columns:

   Id (PK), TournamentId (FK), Date, Time, Court, Venue, TeamA_ID(FK - TournamentLogs.Id), TeamB_ID(FK - TournamentLogs.Id)

Both tables contains some other info which is not required for what I'm trying to do here. Getting most of the info is easy because I pass through the tournamentId as paramenter to the query, but my problem arrises when I try to get the team names for team A and B in my query. Currently I try to set them as variables and retrieve them with the `TeamA_ID/TeamB_ID` values from `TournamentFixtures`. Obviously I'm not doing this right, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far-

```
SELECT  TournamentFixtures.Id,
        TournamentFixtures.TournamentId,
        TournamentFixtures.Date,
        TournamentFixtures.Time,
        TournamentFixtures.Venue,
        TournamentFixtures.Court,

        TournamentLogs.Section,
        TournamentLogs.Gender,      
        SET @TeamA = (SELECT TournamentLogs.Team from TournamentLogs where TournamentLogs.Id = TournamentFixtures.TeamA_ID)
        SET @TeamB = (SELECT TournamentLogs.Team from TournamentLogs where TournamentLogs.Id = TournamentFixtures.TeamB_ID)

FROM TournamentFixtures
Where TournamentFixtures.TournamentId = '1' //will pass this parameter through as required
```

I'm a novice a SQL so this might be way of the right track. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use two joins to bring in the information you are looking for.  Your query will fail with a syntax error, because `TournamentLogs` is not in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT tf.Id, tf.TournamentId, tf.Date, tf.Time, tf.Venue, tf.Court,
       tla.Section, tla.Gender, tla.Team as TeamA, tlb.Team as TeamB 
FROM TournamentFixtures tf LEFT JOIN
     TournamentLogs tla
     ON tla.id = tf.TeamA_ID LEFT JOIN
     TournamentLogs tlb
     ON tlb.id = tf.TeamB_ID 
Where tf.TournamentId = '1' //will pass this parameter through as required
```

Because you are joining twice to the same table, you need to use table aliases.  These are a good idea anyway, because they make the query easier to write and to read.

I don't know what you mean by assigning variables.  That seems unnecessary for your logic.

Comment: this works perfectly! Though you might just edit your answer a bit, the 2nd column in your select is a typo I suspect :-)